# Difference UI for portrait and landscape ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, screen-orientation

I would like to create an application like this:
[image]

On iphone (both portrait and landscape) and ipad portrait, I have a table view screen, tap on item row will navigate to another detail screen look like other basic application. 
But when I rotate screen to go to landscape on ipad, the screen now has two section views 
Here is what I did:

- Write  a method `isInLandscapeTablet` to detect ipad landscape
- Use `UINavigationController` as a **root controller** to control all other views
- In portrait screen, push a viewcontroller contains tableview to root controller
- In landscape tablet screen, attach tableview controller and detail controller to `UISplitViewController`, then push it into root controller

But the problem is I can't push UISplitViewController to root  controller, as it requires to be a root controller.
I wonder how I can handle this problem
And is my approach correct? Is there any other way?

**Update**: I change the root view controller like this

```
  // this snippet is in UINavigationController (I use as root viewcontroller) 
        if([self isInTabletLandscape]){
             self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[CategoryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CategoryViewController" bundle:nil], self.propertyLandViewController, nil];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setRootViewController:self.splitViewController];
        }else{
 // it doesn't work
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setRootViewController:self];
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should have three different viewController - 1 for iPhone portrait, 1 for iPad portrait, 1 for iPad landscape (with splitViewController). push the correct viewcontroller to the rootViewCcontroller base on device type and orientation. If user rotate iPad, pop to the rootViewControler and push the correct  viewController again. You can set a flag using delegate in the rootViewContoller to tell which viewContoller to push.

Comment: @Kilogen9 this is what I did. But as I said, the problem is I can't push UISplitViewController to root controller, as it requires to be a root controller.

Comment: @R4j is the menu supposed to be static or always showing in landscape?

Comment: @NorthBlast it isn't really a menu. The view 1 always displays on the left on ipad landscape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is not to use Split View Controller at all. Create a custom View Controller, which will embed your table view controller and the 2nd controller. Also, you can implement the interface-rotation logic in the custom controller you create.

Comment: Do you have any example for custom view controller act like split view controller?

Comment: I have experience in creating different custom controllers. If you are new in iOS development, I recommend you to use Container View in storyboard. That view can be found in objects inspector. It provides **embed** segue to custom child controller. Use two containers, for the table and for the detail.

Comment: It looks promise. I will have a try.Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

After knowing the device whether it is iPad or iPhone. You Can try to remove the RootViewController.

```
       appDelegate.window.rootViewController = nil;
```

Then you set the root view controller with a new SplitViewContloller

```
        id objClass =[[SplitViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SplitViewController" bundle:nil];
        masterVC.delegate = detailVC;
        detailVC.delegate = objClass;
        [objClass setViewControllers:@[masterNavigate,detailNavigate]];

        [appDelegate.window setRootViewController:objClass];
```

Comment: I updated my question. This way will works when I rotate to landscape. But when I change from landscape to portrait, it display the detail view of splitview controller instead of my root view controller

Comment: Could you share the code over github. So that i can help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing on iOS 8 you should use [Size Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH6-SW1), so you can totally change the layout depending on iPhone/iPad portrait and iPad Landscape. Unfortunately on iOS 7, size classes only differentiate iPhone and iPad.

In both case the right part (2), can be easily handle with a containerView.

Comment: well, I know size classes, but I don't think it can help for my case. As it isn't only difference UI but also difference the logic. What I need is the correct way to organize the view hierarchy to handle view logic

Answer (score 1):

[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/SplitViewControllers.html](http://Apple's%20Documentation%20For%20SplitView%20Controller%20in%20iOS)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   MyFirstViewController* firstVC = [[MyFirstViewController alloc] init];
   MySecondViewController* secondVC = [[MySecondViewController alloc] init];

if ( ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] ==  UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)  ){

   UISplitViewController* splitVC = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
   splitVC.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstVC, secondVC, nil];

    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    window.rootViewController = splitVC;
   [window makeKeyAndVisible];
 }
    else
{
// Display tableview

}
 return YES;
 }
```

I assume this may help you..

Comment: It look like the James's answer below. When rotate from landscape to portrait, it display the view2 instead of tableview (view 1). Here is my snippet: http://pastebin.com/DAs38PsU